# Как объяснить "то" ("то, что называется") в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

> Актёр должен убедительно существовать, то, что зритель называет
>   “играть”, и ведь продолжать играть, и играть одно и то же на
>   протяжении многих лет, и в любом настроении – это такая работа.

*...Существовать, то, что зритель называет "играть"...*

Пунктуация моя; верна ли?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо, отступление *то, что зритель называет “играть”* придётся обособить "хирургическими" средствами: "оно" всячески рассогласовано с остальным текстом, и нужно его соотнести исключительно с глаголом "существовать". Запятая после "лет" выглядит лишней (запятая перед первым "и" оправдана тем, что "и" имеет значение "причём"); вместо "и ведь" (из-за множественных "и", путающихся своими разными смыслами) просится "а ведь" (только что дано определение "существованию", и надо обозначить его окончание - хотя бы "менее связующим" союзом, но можно и точку поставить):

> Актёр должен убедительно существовать - то, что зритель называет
>   “играть”; а ведь продолжать играть, и играть одно и то же на
>   протяжении многих лет и в любом настроении – это такая работа.